# Event for customers who choose to Register upon checking out

Tags: magento

I've created an observer for customer_registration_success, but I need to listen to the event that is triggered on one page checkout, when a user chooses to **register**. http://cl.ly/image/2F3L0s1E3g1e

Any thoughts on what event this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own 'custom event' using the logic below to check which method they use to check out on success.phtml or incorporate it in `sales_order_place_after`

```
$quoteId = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId())->getQuoteId();
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$method = $quote->getCheckoutMethod(true);
if ($method == 'register'){
//the customer registered...do your stuff
}
```

Source : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/273690/#t375160

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Looks like this won't tell me what route the user is taking until after the order is complete. I was really hoping that I could somehow listen for the click event, or whatever event is triggered upon them selecting their method. Might write a simple JS script to listen for the click event, and act on that -- not ideal, but a viable solution for the short term. If you have any other suggestions, I'd appreciate it.